# Calculate the distance between all other points in a TSV file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, math

I have a TSV file filled with n data points and I want to calculate the distances between all of the points. I have something like this:

[image: TSV example]

What I thought about doing was the `.iloc` feature

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_csv('data.tsv', sep='\t')
print (x)

while True: xcord= (int)
```

I was thinking you could do where you add 1 to each point iteratively, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by `distance between all other points`? Can you give us an example of expected output?

Comment: Yes, sorry! For example, the distance between A an B is d = 4.073928. Between A and C is d = 3.06557. Then I want the distance between A and D, A and E, and so on. Also I'd want the distances between B and C, B and D, and so on. The results would ideally look like a correlation matrix where 0 is self and then you have the distances between the other 20 points screenshotted. The formula I'm using is sqrt((x2-x1)^2 +(y2-y1)^2 +( z2-z1)^2)

Comment: If my answer solved your issue could you mark it as accepted?

Comment: That code you show is not really an attempt. For example, it does not include the `.iloc` feature you mention in your text. Please show an actual code attempt on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution using `distance_matrix`

You can proceed using [`scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html).

Suppose your DataFrame is `my_dataframe`.

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp    

points = pd.DataFrame(my_dataframe, columns=["X", "Y", "Z"]).astype(float)
distance_matrix = sp.spatial.distance_matrix(points, points)
```

### Visualising the result

We can use [`seabord.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) to visualise the obtained results:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

labels = my_dataframe["points"]

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 10]
plt.axis('scaled')
sns.heatmap(distance_matrix,
        annot=True,
        cbar = False,
        fmt="0.2f",
        cmap="YlGnBu",
        xticklabels=labels,
        yticklabels=labels)
plt.title("Distance matrix")
```

**The result is:**

[image]

### A small textual example

We can create a small textual example with which we may help understand step by step inputs and outputs. Let's consider a DataFrame with just two points:

#### Generating an example dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.random.uniform(100, size=(2, 3))
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([[["A"], ["B"]], a]), columns=["points", "X", "Y", "Z"])
```

The DataFrame we have generated looks like:

[image: Example DataFrame]

#### Splitting points and labels

We split the labels and the points:

```
points = pd.DataFrame(my_dataframe, columns=["X", "Y", "Z"]).astype(float)
labels = my_dataframe["points"]
```

So `points` looks like:

[image: Points]

And `labels` looks like:

[image: Labels]

#### Calculating the distance matrix

Now we can proceed calculating the distance matrix executing `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`:

```
distance_matrix = sp.spatial.distance_matrix(points, points)
```

**The resulting matrix is:**

```
array([[ 0.        , 93.43955419],
       [93.43955419,  0.        ]])
```

#### Visualising the obtained matrix

Using the same code as above, we obtain:

[image: Small distance matrix]